# How to define namespace in python?

Tags: python

It seems that python do have namespaces. But All I can get is people telling me what namespace or scope is. So how do you define a namespace in python? All I need is the syntax (and with an example would be much better).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913217/what-are-python-namespaces-all-about

Comment: @j4ck So which answer to that question has already answer my question?

Comment: The first one. Name spaces are nothing you can explicitly `define`. They're given by the scope you're coding in.

Comment: For example, if you define a variable within a function definition, that variable is within the scope and namespace of this function only, meaning other functions or parts of code cannot see it.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/) might help to shed some more light ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "namespace" in Python is defined more by the layout of the code on disk than it is with any particular syntax. Given a directory structure of:

```
my_code/
    module_a/
        __init__.py
        a.py
        b.py
    module_b/
        __init__.py
        a.py
        b.py
    __init__.py
    main.py
```

and assuming each `a.py` and `b.py` file contains a function, `fn()`, the import syntax to resolve the namespace works like so (from `main.py`):

```
from module_a.a import fn  # fn() from module_a/a.py
from module_a.b import fn  # fn() from module_a/b.py
from module_b.a import fn  # fn() from module_b/a.py
from module_b.b import fn  # fn() from module_b/b.py
```

At this point, `fn()` is available within `main.py` and will call whichever implementation you imported.

It's also possible to use the `from module import *` syntax, but this is discouraged in favour of being more specific:

```
from module_a.a import *
```

Here, `fn()` is available within `main.py`, and also *any other symbol defined in `module_a/a.py`*.

If we want to have access to both `module_a/a.py`'s `fn()` and also the `fn()` from `module_b/b.py`, we can do one of two things: either we use the `from module import thing as something` syntax:

```
from module_a.a import fn as module_a_fn
from module_b.b import fn as module_b_fn
```

and use them in our `main.py` as `module_a_fn()` and `module_b_fn()`, or we can just import the module and reference it directly in the code, so in `main.py`:

```
import module_a.a
import module_a.b

module_a.a.fn()  # call fn() from module_a/a.py
module_a_b.fn()  # call fn() from module_a/b.py
```

I hope that helps elucidate the usage a bit more.

Comment: This answer doesn't consider Classes, NamedTuples, or other things that define scope and are therefore namespaces.