# Caesar Cipher Encrypt, can't print final message

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

```
def message():
    answer1 = input('Welcome to the Caesar Cipher! What do you want to encrypt?')
    key = input('Enter the key number that you want to encrypt with. (1 - 26)')


def getMessage():
    while leng <= lengthOfInput1-1:
        lengthList.append(chr(ord(answer1[len]) + key))
        len += 1
    print(lengthList)


key = 0
answer1 = ''
maxKeySize = 26
lengthOfInput1 = len(answer1)
leng = 0
lengthList = []
message()
getMessage()
```

When I run this code, I always get the answer back as '[ ]'. I don't know what is going on and thought that the variable, 'lengthList' was a list and would append the letters. I also need help with having the individual letters go together to form an encrypted message.
Thanks, Eric

Comment: You only change `answer1` and `key` in the function. Those values are not related to `answer1` and `key` you defined in the outer scope. Use `return` to give back those values from the function. In the function you'll have `return (answer1, key)` and you'll have to call the function with `answer1, key = message()`.

Comment: [Namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913217/what-are-python-namespaces-all-about)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's is happening because you have not assigned your `answer1` variable in the outer. In the `message()` method you have assigned the values to variables local to it's scope, and not the `answer1` variable in the outer scope as you wanted.

You would have to pass it as a parameter, and return it's value so that it retains it's value.

Similarly, getMessage() cannot access variables which are outside it's scope. So, you have to pass them as a parameter too!

A correct form of this code would look like:

```
def message():
    answer1 = input('Welcome to the Ceaser Cipher! What do you want to encrypt?')
    key = int(input('Enter the key number that you want to encrypt with. (1 - 26)'))
    return answer1, key


def getMessage(lengthOfInput1, lengthList, answer1, key, leng):
    while leng <= lengthOfInput1-1:
        lengthList.append(chr(ord(answer1[leng]) + key))
        leng += 1
    print(lengthList)


key = 0
answer1 = ''
answer1, key = message()
# Here I am returning both of the values from
# message method.

# LOCAL VARIABLES
maxKeySize = 26
lengthOfInput1 = len(answer1)
leng = 0
lengthList = []

getMessage(lengthOfInput1, lengthList, answer1, key, leng)
# Inorder to access the local variables, you will
# have to pass them to getMessage() method.
```

This above piece of code, will make a list `lengthList` which contains the letters of the cipher. However, it is local to `getMessage()`. You would have to return it to it's parent scope, to access it there.

Moreover, to make convert a list to a string, you would have to iterate within the list, and keep appending to an empty string. Something like this:

```
messageCoded = ""
for i in messageList:
    messageCoded += i

print(messageCoded)
```

Make sure you keep the scopes correct, and you will do good. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/8726146) article explains in a well and good way.

Answer (score 1):

With minimal changes in your original code the working code is

```
def message():
    answer = input('Welcome to the Ceaser Cipher! \nWhat do you want to encrypt? ')
    key = input('Enter the key number that you want to encrypt with (1 - 26): ')
    return answer, int(key)


def getMessage(answer, key):
    lengthList = []
    leng = 0
    while leng < len(answer):
        lengthList.append(chr(ord(answer[leng]) + key))
        leng += 1
    print("".join(lengthList))


answer, key = message()
getMessage(answer, key)
```

*The explanation:*

1. Your `message()` function fill the `answer1` and `key` variables with user input but then *throw them out*, because these are only *local* variables - `answer1` and `key` out of the definition of this function are *others* variables.
   So I included the `return` command to save them (and renamed `answer1` to simply `answer`).
2. The type of key variable in your message() function is str (string), but you need int. So the `int(key)` in the return statement.
3. In the main code I saved those returned values - the `answer, key = message()` command.
4. Your function `getMessage()` needs those values, so I added them as parameters to it - `def getMessage(answer, key):`
5. I moved the commands

   ```
   lengthList = []
   leng = 0
   ```

   into the definition of the function `getMessage()`.
6. I change your `while leng <= lengthOfInput1-1:` command to `while leng < len(answer):` - note `<` instead of `<=`.
7. You want to print as a result a *string*, not a `list` of individual characters - so I changed that list to a string with the `"".join(lengthList)` command. (The empty string `""` is used as a delimiter between individual joined letters, so they will be joined without spaces or other symbols.)
8. And I deleted all superfluous (useless) statements.