# Cannot increment a global variable in the __init__ function Python

Tags: python, variables, global, init

I'm trying to increment a global variable called "lastIdentify" in the `__init__` and I can not do it.

```
class Agent:

   lastIdentify = 0

   def __init__(self,name,tel,age,gender='ND'):
      global lastIdentify
      lastIdentify += 1
      self._identify = lastIdentify
```

I also tried deleting the global statement and nothing happened.

I have this error:
File "/.../A/Agent.py", line 10, in **init**
lastIdentify += 1
NameError: name 'lastIdentify' is not defined

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you do it?

Comment: There's no reason why this shouldn't work. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure it's a global variable, not a class variable?

Comment: There is no sign of a class in the code you provided. Please post a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as Barmar thought, you had a class variable in mind.

The tricky part here is:   Python has mutable data (lists, dictionaries, sets...) and immutable data (ints, floats, strings...).

When you modify a class level immutable variable you copy and bind it to the instance's scope/namespace.  That is what is happening on `badlastIdentify`.

On the other hand, if you start mutating a class-scoped mutable attribute, for example a list, you'd find that you are modifying the class-level variable, i.e. your list would get bigger all around, even if that is not what you wanted.

And, in your original code, `global lastIdentify` was something yet again:  it didn't previously exist, could not be incremented, and had **no** relation to your class.  Generally speaking, `global` as a keyword in Python is a bit of a code smell, it's usually better handled differently.  And, no, I am not a person who gets all religious about globals and singletons being bad, just specifically when `global` is being used.

```
class Agent:

   lastIdentify = 0
   badlastIdentify = 0

   def __init__(self,name,tel,age,gender='ND'):

      # you are operating on the class namespace, 
      #not on an instance-specific variable
      self.__class__.lastIdentify += 1

      #this doesnt "mutate" the class-variable
      #it binds a new copy of it, +1, to this instance
      self.badlastIdentify += 1

agent99 = Agent(1,2,3,4)
agent007 = Agent(1,2,3,4)

print(f"{agent99.badlastIdentify=} , {agent99.lastIdentify=} ")
print(f"{agent007.badlastIdentify=} , {agent007.lastIdentify=} " )
print(f"{Agent.badlastIdentify=}  {Agent.lastIdentify=} ")
```

### output:

```
agent99.badlastIdentify=1 , agent99.lastIdentify=2
agent007.badlastIdentify=1 , agent007.lastIdentify=2
Agent.badlastIdentify=0  Agent.lastIdentify=2
```

see also:

[What are Python namespaces all about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913217/what-are-python-namespaces-all-about)
["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument/11416002)

Comment: I edited my post, it is defined in a python class.