# Is there any subtle difference between the terms Namespace and Identifier?

Tags: python, programming-languages

I tried looking around on this but search for each of them returned similar meanings for both of the terms. I was curious if there's still any difference between these two, or they can be used interchangeably?

Edit: As suggested, it might depend on language. I would like to ask this for Python.

Comment: It would depend on the language, but in all the languages I've used they're *very* different. For example, the name of a variable is typically an identifier - but it isn't a namespace...

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question and set it specific to Python. Okay so I somehow get what's is an identifier. Though any examples for namespace?

Comment: The terms don't mean anything like each other. This is like asking whether there is a difference between the terms "breadbox" and "loaf". The namespace is a container for identifiers.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913217/what-are-python-namespaces-all-about help? I found it by putting `python what is a namespace` into a search engine. What happened when you tried that? Or else, what search terms did you try?

Comment: I see @KarlKnechtel I think it makes more sense to me now.

Comment: Actually I tried searching the exact same term and first answer was from geeksforgeeks.org where they said:
> A namespace is a system that has a unique name for each and every object in Python. An object might be a variable or a method. Python itself maintains a namespace in the form of a Python dictionary. ... Its Name (which means name, a unique identifier) + Space(which talks something related to scope).

It just didn't digest me well haha.

Now after you mentioned the 'container' this made sense to me.