# Python: Import function from .py file with required modules

Tags: python, function, module

I am trying to do something fairly simple. I want to import a function from a .py file but use modules imported in my primary script. For instance the following function is stored

./files/sinner.py

```
def sinner(x):
  y = mt.sin(x)
  return y
```

I then want to run sinner using the math as mt

```
from sinner import sinner
import math as mt
sinner(10)
```

This not surprisingly throws an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-50006877ce3e> in <module>()
      2 import math as mt
      3 
----> 4 sinner(10)

/media/ssd/Lodging_Classifier/sinner.py in sinner(x)
      1 import math as mt
----> 2 
      3 def sinner(x):
      4   y = mt.sin(x)
      5   return y

NameError: global name 'mt' is not defined
```

I know how to handle this in R, but not in Python. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to do `import math` in `sinner.py`. Every module is its own namespace. When the main module imports `sinner.py`, it gets access to `sinner.py`'s namespace: not the other way around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: why can't an imported module reference another imported module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909002/python-why-cant-an-imported-module-reference-another-imported-module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import math in sinner.py. It will import the function with all it's dependencies in the file. if a dependency it not present in the file it will not work.

sinner.py

```
import math as mt

def sinner(x):
  y = mt.sin(x)
  return y
```

then in your other file...

```
from sinner import sinner
sinner(10)
```

Comment: Yep that works. Thought I had tried that, but apparently I mistyped something... silly.

Comment: @mmann1123 If this is correct do you mind selecting it as the answer to help others in the future.

Answer (score 5):

The math module does not exist in the `sinner.py` namespace. Unlike R, imported modules or packages do not span the global namespace. You need to import `math` in the `sinner.py` file:

```
import math as mt

def sinner(x):
  y = mt.sin(x)
  return y
```

Alternatively (and I really don't know why you'd do this), you can pass the module as an arg to the `sinner` function:

```
def sinner(mt, x):
  y = mt.sin(x)
  return y
```

And then you could pass different modules that implement the `sin` function:

```
from .sinner import sinner
import math as mt
import numpy as np
sinner(mt, 10)
sinner(np, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also pass mt as a parameter to sinner

```
def sinner(x, mt): code
```