# Python modules import problem: import statement in different location

Tags: python, import

Here's my folder structure:

```
main.py
tools/
  sub1.py
  sub2.py
```

where main.py:

```
import tools.sub1
import tools.sub2
```

and sub1.py:

```
a = 'abc'
```

and sub2.py (directly import sub1 is not working, is it because I am running main.py from the root directory?):

```
import tools.sub1
print(tools.sub1)
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909002/python-why-cant-an-imported-module-reference-another-imported-module), I knew that in order to correctly call sub1, sub2 from main, we have to add the statement **import tools.sub1** in sub2, however, if I want to run sub2 individually, error occurs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sub2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tools.sub1 as sub1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools'
```

So, My question is that **is it possible to directly run sub2 individually, while keeping the current design that we can properly run main.py?**. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run *sub2* using `python -m tools.sub2`

More info on using *-m* https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by making `tools` a python module. Adding an `__init__.py` file (can be empty) in your tools directory will make Python consider the "tools" folder a module. You can then reference `sub1` from both `main.py` and `sub2.py` with:

```
from tools import sub1
```